# ffmpeg: Too many bits per frame requested

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, h.264

Sometimes there is an issue when i try to convert to mp4 using `ffmpeg`. I'm getting issue `Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`.

This is the command:

```
 ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'scale=-2:360,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-20:(main_h-overlay_h)-20' -codec:v libx264 -profile:v main -preset slow -b:v 300k -maxrate 300k -bufsize 600k -threads 0 -codec:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128k -crf 20 output.mp4 1> output.log 2>&1
```

Here the error log:

```
ffmpeg version 2.4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Nov 16 2014 22:36:57 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/man --docdir=/usr/doc/ffmpeg-2.4.3 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libass --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libzvbi --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-debug --arch=x86_64 --enable-pic --extra-cflags='-I/tmp/build/tmp-ffmpeg/ffmpegdeps/usr/include -DRUNTIME_CPUDETECT' --extra-ldflags='-L/tmp/build/tmp-ffmpeg/ffmpegdeps/usr/lib64 -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lusb' --pkg-config-flags=--static
      libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
      libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
      libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
      libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
      libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
      libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
      libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
      libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
      libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
      Duration: 00:00:06.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1856 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480, 1804 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 54 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Input #1, png_pipe, from 'watermark.png':
      Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba, 120x35, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    [libx264 @ 0x2179d80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64 SlowShuffle
    [libx264 @ 0x2179d80] profile Main, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 0x2179d80] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=300 vbv_bufsize=600 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [aac @ 0x217ba40] Too many bits per frame requested
    Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 540x360, q=-1--1, 300 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
          encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 aac
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
      Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
      overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Please include the **complete** console output.

Comment: Ok, i added full output log.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant messages:

> ```
> [aac @ 0x217ba40] Too many bits per frame requested
> […]
> Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1
> ```

This is from the native FFmpeg AAC encoder named "`aac`". Your options:

- [Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the input AAC audio instead of re-encoding (`-c:a copy`).
- Use a different AAC encoder. This would require re-compiling `ffmpeg` because your build appears to only support the native FFmpeg AAC encoder.
- Use a lower audio bitrate (`-b:a`).
- Use a higher audio rate (`-ar`).

Other notes

- `-b:v` and `-crf` are mutually exclusive: you should choose only one. In you case `-b:v` was ignored.
- `-threads 0` is the default for this encoder, meaning that x264 will automatically select the appropriate number of threads, so you can remove this option.
- The H.264 profile (`-profile:v`) only needs to be set if your target players or devices do not support whatever profile the encoder automatically selects.
- FFmpeg 2.4.3 is considered old. General users are recommended to use `ffmpeg` from current git master if possible (meaning use a build from the most recent code). [Downloading a static build](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) is an easy way to do that.
- Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. If you have additional `ffmpeg` cli usage questions they should be asked at Super User.

Comment: `-c:a copy` fixed if for me.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your AAC audio stream #0:1. It shows *0 channels* in the console output.

Try adding `-analyzeduration` and `-probesize` to your command to increase the analysis time and see if it detects them or drop the audio stream entirely / check the source file integrity.

> **probesize integer (input)**
>
> Set probing size in bytes, i.e. the size of
> the data to analyze to get stream information. A higher value will
> enable detecting more information in case it is dispersed into the
> stream, but will increase latency. Must be an integer not lesser than
> 32. It is 5000000 by default.
>
> **analyzeduration integer (input)**
>
> Specify how many microseconds are
> analyzed to probe the input. A higher value will enable detecting more
> accurate information, but will increase latency. It defaults to
> 5,000,000 microseconds = 5 seconds.

Comment: Is it can help to fix issue or just analyze video encoding procces?

Comment: It will analyze the input file for longer before starting to encode in order to try and get the correct audio codec information. You need to put them before your input `ffmpeg -probesize ### -analyzeduration ### -i input.mp4 ...`